# How to have a post method with some parameters and get back successful response from server

Tags: java, jquery, struts2

I am trying this to get json object but it does not seem to work

```
$.post("/csm/compare.action",
          { 
            sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
            compareCategory: "system",
            compareSubCategory:"patch",
            xml1:absP[0],
            xml2:absP[1]},
              function(data)
              {


                alert(data.response[0].elementName);
}
        );
```

Part of my json that gets returned

```
{
"response": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "elementName": "Accounting.ACCT-ENG-A-MAN",
        "subCategory": "patch",
        "isEqual": false,
        "isPrasentinXml1": true,
        "isPrasentinXml2": true,
        "attribute": [
            {
                "name": "information",
                "firstValue": "Acco",
                "secondValue": "Acco"
            },
            {
                "name": "name",
                "firstValue": "Accounting.ACCT-ENG-A-MAN",
                "secondValue": "Accounting.ACCT-ENG-A-MAN"
            },
            {
                "name": "version",
                "firstValue": "B.11.23",
                "secondValue": "B.11.23"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: What are you using for server side? Is it  ASP.net MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$.post("/csm/compare.action",
          { 
            sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
            compareCategory: "system",
            compareSubCategory:"patch",
            xml1:absP[0],
            xml2:absP[1]},
              function(data)
              {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);

                alert(data.response[0].elementName);
}
        );
```

Comment: @genisis: Is there any thing such as success method?

Comment: @genisis: Can i alert the whole response as a string?

Comment: as a string? yes,  alert(data);
 before that my line

Comment: @genisis: it gives me `Object XmlDocument`

Comment: put it after the `data=$.parseJson(data);`

Comment: Now even the alert  does not come

Comment: My Firefox firebug show error at `data=$.parseJson(data);` says `Error: $.parseJson is not a function
Source File: http://in164263:10070/csm/view/include/js/custom/popupCompareConfig.js
Line: 296`

Comment: sorry, it should be parseJSON not parseJson

Comment: It gives me only 1 alert with `null` as its value for these commands  `data=$.parseJSON(data);
                    alert(data);
                    alert(data.response[0].elementName);`

Comment: so there's problem with your backend

Comment: @genesis: You are correct. I had to give `application/json`. now it comes properly. Thanks for helping out

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.post('"/csm/compare.action"',
 { 
            sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
            compareCategory: "system",
            compareSubCategory:"patch",
            xml1:absP[0],
            xml2:absP[1]},
            function(data){
                alert(data);
                alert(data.response[0].elementName);
            }, 'json');
```

not sure whether it'll help or not but you can try it anyway also if you use `$.ajax` instead of `post` you can make an `error` call back that will give a more insight

try this if the above fails

```
$.post("/csm/compare.action",
          { 
            sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
            compareCategory: "system",
            compareSubCategory:"patch",
            xml1:absP[0],
            xml2:absP[1]},
              function(data)
              {
                data = JSON.parse(data);   <-- the change is here
                alert(data);
                alert(data.response[0].elementName);
}
        );
```

the ajax equivalent is

```
$.ajax({

url:'/csm/compare.action',
type:'POST',
data:{
        sessiontoken: sessiontoken,
        compareCategory: "system",
        compareSubCategory:"patch",
        xml1:absP[0],
        xml2:absP[1]
},
cache:false,
success:function(data){
data = JSON.parse(data);
alert(data);
},
error:function(jqxhr){
alert(jqxhr.status);
alert(jqxhr.responseText);
}
```

});

Comment: How can I make a `$.ajax` call here? Currently it is calling post inside a function

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1, there was no problem at the client side, but the server side, i did not gave json content type as `application/json`. Now it works

Comment: .post is only shortcut for .ajax

Comment: just wanted to add the `error` thats why gave the `ajax` suggestion ... glad that the prb is solved ...